# Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting with dominant diagonal

Tags: matrices

Why is it that there is no need for row replacement when performing Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting on a matrics with a dominant diagonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few posts asking this question. Here is my answer:

We only need to show that after eliminating $a_{2,1}$, diagonal dominance is preserved, i.e.,
$$
\left|a_{2,2}-a_{1,2}{a_{2,1}\over a_{1,1}}\right|>\sum_{i=3}^n\left|a_{2,i}-a_{1,i}{a_{2,1}\over a_{1,1}}\right|,
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$
|a_{2,2}a_{1,1}-a_{1,2}a_{2,1}|>\sum_{i=3}^n|a_{2,i}a_{1,1}-a_{1,i}a_{2,1}|.
$$
But this is true:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=3}^n|a_{2,i}a_{1,1}-a_{1,i}a_{2,1}|&\le& 
|a_{1,1}|\sum_{i=3}^n|a_{2,i}|+|a_{2,1}|\sum_{i=3}^n|a_{1,i}| \\
&<& |a_{1,1}|(|a_{2,2}|-|a_{2,1}|)+|a_{2,1}|(|a_{1,1}|-|a_{1,2}|) \\
&=&|a_{1,1}||a_{2,2}|-|a_{2,1}||a_{1,2}|\\
&\le& |a_{1,1}a_{2,2}-a_{2,1}a_{1,2}|
\end{eqnarray*}